# Why add Vary on Access-Control-Request-Method, ACRH and origin when OPTIONS method is not cacheable?

Tags: http, cors

I found go implementation of CORS and it adds on every CORS request following headers:

```
headers.Add("Vary", "Origin")
headers.Add("Vary", "Access-Control-Request-Method")
headers.Add("Vary", "Access-Control-Request-Headers")
```

https://github.com/rs/cors/blob/f9bce55a4e61e3d1a061993e3453eb9848fcdc4d/cors.go#L269

But as far as I know OPTIONS method is not cacheable?

So why they add that Vary header?

Comment: https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-protocol-and-http-caches details the rationale for Vary: Origin. As far as using Vary with the Access-Control-Request-\* headers, I don’t know why somebody would do that.

Comment: It's true that `OPTIONS` responses ["are not cacheable"](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-4.3.7). So I'm not sure why they are doing that. The next step would probably be to file an issue on the Github project.

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry For better or worse, some CDNs (e.g. Cloudfront) can be configured to cache responses to `OPTIONS` requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OPTIONS method can be cached by intermediary caches.

For example:

```
If you want OPTIONS responses to be cached, do the following:(...)
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/header-caching.html